# C# put string into textbox from within method

Tags: c#

So the tbVoornaam.Text is an textbox which needs to be filled with a string coming from the database. I have put the string in a listbox before putting it in different variables. These variables are inserted into a method which has to put the strings to textboxes. I am not getting any error whatsoever. The textbox however are all empty when the method is complete.

I am sorry for my crappy English and it might be a stupid question, but I tried to search for it and I cannot find a solution, I have already tried to put it into a loop and use applicatie.DoEver(); like described on the forums but that didn't work. I am still learning C#.

```
       public void WijzigenKlantGegevens(string voornaam, string achternaam, string postcode, string straatnaam, int huisnummer, string woonplaats, string IBAN)
    {

        Wijzigen_klant_gegevens window = new Wijzigen_klant_gegevens();
        window.Show();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
        {

            tbVoornaam.Text = voornaam;
            tbAchternaam.Text = achternaam;
            tbPostcode.Text = postcode;
            tbStraatnaam.Text = straatnaam;
            tbHuisnummer.Text = huisnummer.ToString();
            tbwoonplaats.Text = woonplaats;
            tbIBAN.Text = IBAN;


        }
    }

    private void btnKlantWijzigen_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        string voornaam = _klanten[lbKlanten.SelectedIndex].Voornaam;
        string achternaam = _klanten[lbKlanten.SelectedIndex].achternaam;
        string postcode = _klanten[lbKlanten.SelectedIndex].postcode;
        string straatnaam = _klanten[lbKlanten.SelectedIndex].straatnaam;
        int huisnummer = _klanten[lbKlanten.SelectedIndex].huisnummer;
        string woonplaats = _klanten[lbKlanten.SelectedIndex].woonplaats;
        string iban = _klanten[lbKlanten.SelectedIndex].IBAN;

        Wijzigen_klant_gegevens methode = new Wijzigen_klant_gegevens();
        methode.WijzigenKlantGegevens(voornaam, achternaam, postcode, straatnaam, huisnummer, woonplaats, iban);

    }
```

Comment: there is no need to use a "for loop" that only loops once, make sure that values coming in actually contains data, I think you should use the debugger and see what values are coming in at runtime.

Comment: You're create some form called `Wijzigen_klant_gegevens` and showing it, but you never do anything with that form.  What form has this code on it?  You seem to be setting the text box values on one form, but showing another form.

Comment: sorry for the confusion the text box values are going on the form which needs to show. Because i need to have the values in the textbox, so it can be changed by a use and eventually updated in the database. Basicly opening a existing record and being able to change/update it.

Comment: Use the debugger to see if `voornaam` and other variables in your method actually have data in them. Go [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=eEJ5xKO7c3o) and watch the video to learn debugging. It is a very simple problem you are having and you will be able to figure it out with the debugger.

Comment: yes they are getting values, the tbvoornaam is getting the correct and selected name but not in the textbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're creating a new form and passing it the values:

```
Wijzigen_klant_gegevens methode = new Wijzigen_klant_gegevens();
methode.WijzigenKlantGegevens(voornaam, achternaam, postcode, straatnaam, huisnummer, woonplaats, iban);
```

But then in that method you're creating a *new* form and showing *that* one:

```
Wijzigen_klant_gegevens window = new Wijzigen_klant_gegevens();
window.Show();
```

So now you have *two* instances of the `Wijzigen_klant_gegevens` form.  One which has the values, and another which is shown on the screen.  What you're looking for is just *one* instance of `Wijzigen_klant_gegevens`.  So don't create a new one in your method, just show the existing one:

```
public void WijzigenKlantGegevens(string voornaam, string achternaam, string postcode, string straatnaam, int huisnummer, string woonplaats, string IBAN)
{
    tbVoornaam.Text = voornaam;
    tbAchternaam.Text = achternaam;
    tbPostcode.Text = postcode;
    tbStraatnaam.Text = straatnaam;
    tbHuisnummer.Text = huisnummer.ToString();
    tbwoonplaats.Text = woonplaats;
    tbIBAN.Text = IBAN;
    this.Show();
}
```

(You can also get rid of the loop, since it's not actually looping.)

Comment: THANKS! it is working now, didnt know i could simply use this.Show();